# Explain the output of the java program

Tags: java

I think the output should be "cougar c f", since calling `Cougar()` should just print cougar and call to `go()` should print 'c' for `this.type` and 'f' for `super.type`, since super keyword is used to call the parent class. 
Can anyone please verify this?

```
class Feline {
    public String type = "f ";

    public Feline() {
        System.out.print("feline ");
    }
}

class Cougar extends Feline {
    public Cougar() {
        System.out.print("cougar ");
    }

    void go() {
        type = "c ";
        System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cougar().go();
    }
}
```

Comment: *but it shows incorrect* ? what shows it as incorrect? ... If you simply execute it in an IDE. You would get the result.

Comment: What are you asking....

Comment: I guess this is a question from some exam/certification, is this correct?

Comment: In that case, just a hint: what is implicitly called in the first line of each constructor?

Comment: @Hulk you are right, this is a sample question for oracle. And the super constructor is called implicitly in the first line of each constructor. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hulk but why is `super.type` returning 'c', when it should be 'f', the `type` in parent class?

Comment: @ManishJoshi there is only one `type`, and it is assigned a new value in the first line of `go()`. I.e. `this.type` and `super.type` refer to the same field - one of the reasons to avoid public fields is that they can cause such confusion.

Comment: @Hulk Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the quick answer, the output will be

> feline cougar c c

The reason now.

`new Cougar()` will create an instance `Cougar`, since a `Cougar` is a `Feline`, `Feline`'s constructor is the first thing called in the `Cougar`'s constructor.
This explain "feline cougar".

```
public Cougar() {
    System.out.print("cougar ");
}
```

is actually looking like

```
public Cougar() {
  super(); //printing "Feline"
    System.out.print("cougar ");
}
```

Now, `this.type` and `super.type` both access the same variable declared in `Feline`.

Since you assign `"c"` to it, this explain the output "c c"